# What is the best way to implement skinning in a Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, skinning, skins

Using Rails, I am building several sites which are very similar. I want to implement these as one Rails app answering to multiple domains, and change what is presented and the processing logic based on the domain name. The areas I need to change/skin per site are:

- Views: The fields on a page differ slightly by site. Some sites have more/different fields than others, but there are some that are common across all
- Models (which seems best to do this by defining a super class for the main model which varies and implement a subcalss for each site)
- Controller logic. There is a lot of similarity but a few small processing differences, including which Model subclass to deal with
- CSS (which seems fairly straight forward)

I have already implemented a mechanism which makes the current domain/app name visible to the views, controllers and models.

I was thinking of defining a view partial per site and using ERB logic to include the right one. The controllers seem like the least obvious part.

Any suggestions very much appreciated.

Cheers
Paul

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented something similar for our application, HiringThing (http://www.hiringthing.com)

To do so, we use a before_filter on the application controller that parses request.host and determines what website the request is for. That then sets a variable @site that we reference in views, controllers and models to determine versioning requirements at runtime.